# Che cosa significa "fare pena" in questo contesto?

Tags: meaning

La frase è

> Alcuni esponenti della maggioranza hanno fatto una ottima figura. L’opposizione ha fatto pena.

La traduzione di Google è “Some exponents of the majority have made a good impression. The opposition was sorry.”

È corretta questa traduzione? Ho qualche dubbio. L'opposizione non ha fatto una buona figura, quindi l'opposizione "feels sorry"? "Fare pena" significa "feel sorry"?

Grazie mille per l'aiuto.

Comment: Benvenuto/a su Italian.SE!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, non significa niente di simile a *was sorry* o *feels sorry*.

“Fare pena”, letteralmente, significa “suscitare la compassione” (quindi, semmai, è l'altra persona che *feels sorry* per quella che fa pena) di qualcuno. Spesso, però, lo si usa per dire che qualcuno è patetico o ridicolo. Dal contesto (anche per la contrapposizione con il fatto che altri hanno fatto un'ottima figura), qui il senso è sicuramente questo: secondo chi parla, l'opposizione ha fatto una pessima figura, si è resa ridicola.

Vedi per esempio il punto 2.c della voce [pena](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/pena) del Treccani, con esempi come “ha scritto un articolo che fa pena”.